# spring-boot external configuration entire class

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot

Following these instructions [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) I want to have my MQConnection class properties to be loaded from the application.properties file.

The problem is that the properties are only loaded if I put a @Value("${attributename}") annotation on each and every property. I do not want to tag each and every property, I rather set the class prefix and let spring correlate and map my class properties to those found in application.properties.

**My setup:**

> - application.properties is on the classpath in src/main/resources
> - My @Configuration class also has @EnableConfigurationProperties
> - My MQConnection class has both @Component and @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="mq")

**Configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
 ...
}
```

**MQConnection class:**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="mq")
public class MQConnection{

  @Value("${mq.hostname}") // will only work if @Value is here, don't want this
  private String hostname;
  private int port;
  private String qmanager;
  private String queue;
  private String channel;
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
mq.hostname=localhost
mq.port=5120
mq.qmanager=MyQueueManager
mq.queue=MyQueue
mq.channel=MyChannel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MQConnection` class is not a Java bean (no getters and setters) so Spring can't bind to it. If you don't like getters and setters use Groovy or [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: Ah! That was it. I don't mind getters/setters but I'm curious why it needs to be there. Spring is capable of injecting values on private members without getters/setters, is this not possible (or maybe not desired) with configuration properties? Thanks!

Comment: This is one of the oldest parts if the framework (`BeanWrapper`) and AFAIK there is only a global setting, fields or properties everywhere for everyone. So I think you can't have field setting for your bean without breaking all the other beans in the universe. I'd like to be wrong. But Project Lombok makes it all rather academic anyway, since your classes can have properties without the source code needing them.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem is likely due to be missing the @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation in your configuration file(s) via @Configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, as you can see I have @EnableConfigurationProperties set so that wasn't my problem. It turned out to be the lack of getter/setter as Dave Syer mentioned.